# Problems with running the application using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, mingw, mingw32

Good day, colleagues. I'm building an application using OpenSSL - the application crashes with an error code: 0xc0000142.

The standard application openssl.exe also crashes with this error code. What could be the trouble?

Comment: You have a virus. Please re install the operating system. Hope this helps!

Comment: What is your PC operating system? If you have run 64-bit to 64-bit, I recommend running 32-bit proceses.

Comment: Windows 7. I need to revise the x32 application with openssl

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft Support in [KB 2701373](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2701373):

> This issue is caused by an error in the
>   Microsoft.powershell.consolehost.dll file. When a Windows PowerShell
>   script calls the Console.Write method, or when you run an executable
>   file for an application from a Windows PowerShell session, values are
>   written into the PowerShell console. Additionally, a corresponding
>   console handle is created. When many console handles are created, the
>   console handles leak, and the issue that is described in the
>   "Symptoms" section occurs.

There's also a question in the Microsoft Communities, [CMD.EXE error 0xc0000142](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cmdexe-error-0xc0000142/21efc574-3279-441b-b3fd-005e46914564), and the answer appear to be *"reinstall your application"*.

I'm not sure how MinGW affects the problem. Since MinGW is abandoned, I'm guessing its the problem and you likely won't be able to fix it. Its probably providing an old, buggy version of something with ABI problems.

Maybe you can use Cygwin for Linux on Windows. Cygwin is still actively developed and maintained.

Comment: Use Cygwin.With the parameters: N = 1024, r = 8, p = 0 - job.